# CWebBrowser2 (MFC) GoBack method causing crash when it has nothing to go back to

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc, iwebbrowser2

My application supports the IE (InternetExplorer) browser. When the back/forward buttons are clicked and there is nothing to go back or forward to, `Webbrowser.GoBack()` and `Webbrowser.GoForward()` are causing a crash.

Is there any way to know if I can go back before I actually call `GoBack()`? I took a look at the `CWebBrowser2` class functions, but I couldn't find anything as such.

Is there any API to help on this, or any alternative approach to handle this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau : here is the exact message while I am debugging. "Unhandled exception at 0x7739A6E2 in myapplication.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: COleDispatchException at memory location 0x04A0DCB8. occurred"

Comment: Can you catch the `COleDispatchException` in your code? What is the value of its [`m_wcode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/coledispatchexception-class?view=msvc-160#m_wcode) member?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to know if I can go back before I actually call `GoBack()`?

Per the [`IWebBrowser2::GoBack()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa752121(v=vs.85)) documentation:

> Use the [`DWebBrowserEvents2::CommandStateChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc136546(v=vs.85)) event to check the enabled state of backward navigation. **If the event's [`CSC_NAVIGATEBACK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768361(v=vs.85)) command is disabled, the beginning of the history list has been reached, and the `IWebBrowser2::GoBack` method should not be used.**

And likewise in the [`IWebBrowser2::GoForward`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa752122(v=vs.85)) documentation:

> Use the [`DWebBrowserEvents2::CommandStateChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc136546(v=vs.85)) event to check the enabled state of forward navigation. **If the event's [`CSC_NAVIGATEFORWARD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768361(v=vs.85)) command is disabled, the end of the history list has been reached, and the `IWebBrowser2::GoForward` method should not be used.**

And per [this discussion thread](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/ea206ec868b702ae.htm):

> Create a couple of `BOOL` member variables in the class that processes the
> `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` notifications for the 'back' and 'forward' toolbar
> buttons -- one for each button state. Initialize them both to `FALSE` in
> the ctor. Handle the `OnCommandStateChange` event, and watch for the
> `CSC_NAVIGATEBACK` and `CSC_NAVIGATEFORWARD` values in the 'nCommand'
> parameter. When you get the `CSC_NAVIGATEBACK` value store the 'Enable'
> parameter value into your `BOOL` member variable for the 'back' button
> state. Do the same thing for the 'forward' button state variable when
> you get `CSC_NAVIGATEFORWARD` value. In your `OnUpdateButtonForward` and
> `OnUpdateButtonBack` handlers, call `pCmdUI->Enable` using the corresponding
> button state member variable.

So, use the browser's `CSC_NAVIGATE...` state changes to know when it is safe to call `GoBack()/`GoForward()`.  These are the same events that IE uses to enable/disable its own Back/Forward UI toolbar buttons.